# UITableViewController cell modal pass data to next UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, cell

I know we can do "cell" push in a navigation style passing some data to next UIViewController.
But, Can we also do it like, a prototype cell "modal" pass data to next UIViewController?
here are part of my tableview implementation.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.chatPeople count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"chatCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *fn = [[self.chatPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *ln = [[self.chatPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"last_name"];

    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fn, ln];
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    return cell;
}
```

and now i am trying to pass 3 NSStrings to destination ViewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSString *toChatEmailID = [[self.chatPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *fn = [[self.chatPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *ln = [[self.chatPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"last_name"];

    MessagesViewController *messageVc = [segue destinationViewController];
    messageVc.firstName = fn;
    messageVc.lastName = ln;
    messageVc.passedOverEmailID = @"1";
}
```

and now in my destination VC, i wish the title of this VC to be displayed as "firstname + lastname"

```
@interface MessagesViewController ()

@end

@implementation MessagesViewController

@synthesize menuBtn;
@synthesize chatBtn;
@synthesize passedOverEmailID;
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstName,lastName);
    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chatting with %@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}
```

and here is what error is:

```
[ChatViewController setPassedOverEmailID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b4e0c0
2014-04-28 21:36:41.033 WeNetwork[1895:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ChatViewController setPassedOverEmailID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b4e0c0'
```

can anyone give me some help, cheers

Comment: Your error tells you that the class ChatViewController doesn't have a property called passedOverEmailID, but in your code you are trying to set the passedOverEmailID on a MessagesViewController class.  Are you sure the segue.destinationViewController is set up to be MessagesViewController in your storyboard?  Your error would indicate that it is not.  Also, I always like to cast the class type when referencing a segue.destinationViewController, so I'd suggest using MessagesViewController *messageVc = (MessagesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

Comment: ye, u right....-.- silly me

Answer (score 0):

```
MessagesViewController *messageVc = (MessagesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

this is not correct, the destinationVC should be a different one!